# Disabling 'echo "" exit();' in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, configuration

I have a PHP code base, where I see quite often the following code:

```
echo "" exit();
```

Looks like some debugging output/break, but it's spread over the code, so I assume it cannot be added/removed manually all the time. Is this a well known PHP technique or pattern? Is there some setting in php.ini where I somehow can switch the behavior of this line? How do I prevent the code from stopping all the time at this line?

Comment: Does it compile? Shouldn't it be `echo ""; exit();` or am I missing something?

Comment: Comment them all out? `// echo ""; exit();` or remove them completely

Comment: try this `ini_set('disable_functions', 'exit');`

Comment: @michikot: `exit` is builtin, not a function. Also.....

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that `echo "" exit();` will not output anything `""` is an empty string and `exit();` is also an output function but it also stops the script execution.

So if you do not need them why not simply delete 'em all?

Answer (score -1):

Afraid not. The only way to stop that executing is to either wrap it in a setting conditional

```
define('DEBUGGING',1);

if(DEBUGGING == 1) echo "" exit;
```

Or do a find and replace to strip them out.